# SNMP: Finding MIB with OID

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2012, snmp

I have an SNMP agent running Windows Server 2012 (virtualized on VMware). It has been sending traps to the SNMP manager with the following OID: enterprises.5378.2.1.0.1. However, doing a google search of this OID does not return anything, and I can't find the MIB, which would translate this OID to a string which states what the trap is for. Is there another way to get this MIB?

Comment: Contact the [owner](http://www.iana.org/assignments/enterprise-numbers/enterprise-numbers)  of the ID: prairiefyre.com. They seem to be Lync-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the MIB called PRAIRIEFYRE-MIB at http://micc.mitel.com/kb/KnowledgebaseArticle52296.aspx